# Graphic of Chebyshev net

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, graphing-functions, surfaces, parametrization

I need to draw in latex the Chebyshev net of surfaces of revolution (Just for this example I don't need to have asymptotic curves, but if I facilitate the calculations it would be great). I have obtained the following

> [image]

I would love to have this graphic,
[image]

I cannot make the precise calculations to be able to obtain it. I know this page is for mathematical development and not LaTeX, I think it would be worth a look. In this [work](https://cermics.enpc.fr/%7Emassony/slides_defense.pdf) several ways are presented in detail but I have not found any to help me answer my question. I have the question here in case anyone wants to see it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617897/chebyshev-net-in-the-sphere-and-catenary